# How do I update a row of data with a button click

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I am kind of new to PHP.

I've been asked to change up a bit of code and add the option to see the status of a field and mark the rows which are completed. So I've added a status field to my MySQL database which has a standard value of 0. Then on button click I'd like this to change to the value 1. Based on this I can either project a cross glyph icon with a button to update this, or project a checkmark so that the status is "done".

Now I'm having issues with the update part. I just cannot seem to get it to work with clicking the button and updating only that row. Field "prdh_num" is my unique value if that is usefull.

Here's the code I work with:

```
    function uren_error(){
    global $mysql;
    $sql = "
                SELECT * 
                FROM uren_error, medw
                WHERE uren_error.uren_datum between adddate(now(),-14) and now() AND medw.medw_num = uren_error.medw_num
                ORDER BY uren_error.prdh_num";
    $query = $mysql->query($sql);

    echo "<h1>Niet in MKG verwerkte uren van de afgelopen 14 dagen</h1>";
    echo "<div class='row' id='urenTabel'>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-0 col-md-0'></div>";
    echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-12'>";
    echo "<table class='table'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<th>Verwerkingsdatum</th>";
    echo "<th>Medewerker</th>";
    echo "<th>Productieorder</th>";
    echo "<th>Productieorder regel</th>";
    echo "<th>Bewerking</th>";
    echo "<th>Duur</th>";
    echo "<th>Status</th>";
    echo "<th>Actie</th>";
    echo "</thead>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        $hours = floor($row['uren_tijd_man_std'] / 3600);
        $mins = floor($row['uren_tijd_man_std'] / 60 % 60);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['uren_datum']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['medw_roepnaam'] . " " . $row['medw_tussenvoegsel'] . " " . $row['medw_naam'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['prdh_num']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['prdr_num']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['bewerk_num']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$hours.":".$mins. "</td>";
        if($row['uren_status'] == "0"){
            echo "<td><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' style='color:red'></div></td>";
            echo "<td><form action'' method='POST'><input type='submit' name=".$row['prdh_num']."></input></form></td>";
        } else if($row['uren_status'] == "1"){
            echo "<td><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok' style='color:green'></div></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

my update code so far:

```
$productieorder = $row['prdh_num'];
$updateStatus = "UPDATE uren_error SET uren_status = 1 WHERE prdh_num=".$productieorder."";
$query2 = $mysql->query($updateStatus);
```

Comment: On click of `submit` button where do you update `<form action'' method='POST'>..</form>` your `action` is empty ,also you missed `=` near `action`  i.e: `action=''` and You need to used `$_POST` to get value .

Comment: I've changed it up a bit so you can see the update code I have so far. It does update every single entry in the database, but not quite on button click and only that row. But it seems like I need to create a new file and add this as my action first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more simple way you can use `<a>` tag to update your record ,instead of `<form>` , just attached your parameter which you need to passed . i.e :

```
echo "<td><a href='currentphppagename.php?prdh_num=".$row['prdh_num']."'></a></td>";
```

And to get `prdh_num` use `$_GET` on same page i.e :

```
 //check if have some value or not
    if (isset($_GET['prdh_num'])) {
    //getting value passed in url
    $productieorder =  $_GET['prdh_num'];
    $updateStatus = "UPDATE uren_error SET uren_status = 1 WHERE prdh_num=".$productieorder."";
    $query2 = $mysql->query($updateStatus);
    }
```

And other way using `form` you can have one hidden field and assign `row` value to that  :

```
echo "<td><form action='' method='POST'><input type='hidden' value=".$row['prdh_num']." name='prdh_num'/><input type='submit' name='submit'></input></form></td>";
```

Now on click of `submit` check below on same page :

```
//check if have some value or not
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //getting value passed in url
    $productieorder =  $_POST['prdh_num'];
    $updateStatus = "UPDATE uren_error SET uren_status = 1 WHERE prdh_num=".$productieorder."";
    $query2 = $mysql->query($updateStatus);
    }
```

Comment: The second way with the form works like a charm! I've added a redirect below the PHP code so that it automaticly sends the user back to the former page. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript. You should put "ondblclick" event on tr tag.

```
<tr ondblclick="Update(rowno)" />
```

And in javascript tag, there must be a function like

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Uptdate(row) {
            window.location.href ="update.php?row="+row;
        }
    </script>
```